# Using split_part and regex for postgres column

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column that has both numbers and their units and I am trying to split it into two columns with regex, but I don't know how to use regex with split_part. Can anyone advise?

This is an example column:

```
|    lot_size1    |
---------+---+-----
| 25,665 Lot SqFt |
| 4,111 Lot SqFt  |
| 14,000 Lot SqFt |
|  Lot SqFt       |
| 40.00 Acres     |
```

This is a draft of my query:

```
select split_part(lot_size1, ???,1) as area,
  split_part(lot_size1, ???,2) as units;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `SUSBTRING`

```
select SUBSTRING ( lot_size1 FROM  '^[0-9,.]+' ) as area ,
       SUBSTRING ( lot_size1 FROM  '[^0-9,.]+' ) as units
       FROM t;
```

`'^[0-9,.]+'` - matches sequence of numbers `,` and `.`

`'[^0-9,.]+'` - matches sequence of anything other than above.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2f9afc735b782134019756bbe7383b4a)

Comment: Thanks!  How would I modify this query to change any empty `area` fields to `NULL`?

Comment: @reallymemorable : It is in fact `null`. Run `\pset null '(null)'` if you're using `psql` to see it.

Comment: How would I eliminate the empty space that appears before the units text?

Comment: @reallymemorable : use trim()