# Split database string column twice in postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, split

I am using ruby on rails with postgresql. I have a table called "teams" with column "team_name". This "team_name" contains values like "1(Team1)", "1(Team2)", "2(Team1)", etc. Now want to take Team1, Team2, Team3 from those team names using sql query. If I use split_part as follows

```
   sql = "SELECT SPLIT_PART(team_name,'(',2) FROM teams where id=20"
   result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

In the result I am getting

```
    [{"split_part"=>"Team1)"}]
```

but I want the following result

```
    [{"split_part"=>"Team1"}]
```

Comment: how about using `SUSBTRING` with regex, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636887/using-split-part-and-regex-for-postgres-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING`, but special characters must be escaped (backslash in this case):

```
Team
  .select("SUBSTRING(team_name FROM '(Team\\d+)') AS team_name")
  .where(id: id)
```

Comment: Thank you but if I use pluck its giving original value instead of substring, anyway I made according changes and its working.